# Inline editing last updated field is not getting saved

Tags: visualforce, jquery, commandbutton, actionfunction, inline-visualforce

I have a pageblock table where i can do some inline editing. But the last editd field is not getting saved. I need to explicitely click elsewhere after editing the field and then click on save and it works fine. For that workaround i have used a jquery method that calls trigger.("blur") oncomplete of that command button. But its not working. the Save method is not being called at all in this scenario :

here is the code :

```
  <script>
        function triggerBlurEvents()
            {
            $("input").trigger("blur");
         Save();
            }
        </script> 
<apex:actionFunction name="Save" action="{!Save}" reRender="thePageBlock" />
          <apex:commandButton value="Save"  oncomplete="triggerBlurEvents();"  id="saveButton"  style="display:none" />
```

Please suggest any work around. thanks !

Comment: Where you able to find a solution for this? We are also stuck at the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this documentation https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_inlineEditSupport.htm. This is how you would do inline edit in a visual force page

Answer (score 0):

In my experience even if you do it right this is a salesforce bug I already discussed here

[Inline editing doesn't update last edited value without control loosing focus first](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/68206/inline-editing-doesnt-update-last-edited-value-without-control-loosing-focus-fi)